# Easiest way to add a 3 second delay, every 30 seconds, in a subtitle to sync it with a video?

Tags: video, sync

I need to sync a subtitle with a video.

By trial and error, I figured out that the subtitle needs a delay of 3 seconds, every 30 seconds. Is there an automated way to do add this delay? I am somewhat familiar with Aegisub and have used it in the past for minor delay corrections - does it have some advanced options to do what I need?

The subtitles are in SubRip Subtitle (SRT) format.

Comment: My easiest solution is to just seach for a different subtitle that does work. It may also be that your video is actually playing too slow, either because your system can't handle it, or there was a conversion error where audio was converted from 48khz to 44khz, slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact format of the subtitles assuming that they are in text format. Mostly you should be able to do that by a self written Python script. Eventually there was Polish app for movies `SubEdit` which had many options to edit subtitles.